# Extract paths and shapes with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, graphics, itext

iTextSharp supports creation of shapes and paths with `PdfContentByte` class, there you can set colors and paint curves and basic elements ... is there a mechanism which does the other way? I am able to get content by calling `PdfReader.GetPageContent(...)` but I didn't find a "parser" to read those operations, apply them to graphics context and for example paint it on a panel.

Example:

```
1 1 1 RG
1 1 1 rg
0.12 0 0 0.12 16 31 cm

q
480 421 m
4318 421 l
4318 5459 l
480 5459 l
480 421 l W n
0.074509806931 0.074509806931 0.074509806931 RG
0.074509806931 0.074509806931 0.074509806931 rg /OC /oc1 BDC
....
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Hi Marc, I want to do the same thing - extracting shapes. Did you have any success in writing a parser or any other solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the starting point of extracting the different commands of a page:

```
    var file = "test.pdf";
    var reader = new PdfReader(file);

    var streamBytes = reader.GetPageContent(2);
    var tokenizer = new PRTokeniser(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(streamBytes));
    var ps = new PdfContentParser(tokenizer);

    List<PdfObject> operands = new List<PdfObject>();
    while (ps.Parse(operands).Count > 0)
    {
        PdfLiteral oper = (PdfLiteral)operands[operands.Count - 1];
        var cmd = oper.ToString();

        switch (cmd)
        {
            case "q":
                Console.WriteLine("SaveGraphicsState(); //q");
                break;

            case "Q":
                Console.WriteLine("RestoreGraphicsState(); //Q");
                break;

           // good luck with the rest!

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported in iTextSharp. The reason: parsing for text returns `TextRenderInfo` objects, parsing for images returns `ImageRenderInfo` objects, but in which form should we return `GraphicsRenderInfo`? It's hard to find something generic, and painting to a graphics context is too specific.

The idea is that you write your own parser, as I did for instance for removing OCG layers: [OCGParser](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/xtra/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/ocg/OCGParser.java). This part of iText hasn't been ported to iTextSharp yet, but maybe you can use it for inspiration.

Note that you're actually building PDF to image functionality. Aren't there other products who already support this out of the box?

Comment: I do not need specifically to render it into on a graphics object, it would be enough to get a general representation like xml or anything ... I will use your link as template thanks for that and try my best!